# What's different between convolution layer in `Torch`(i.e `nn.SpatialConvolution`) and convolution layer in `Pytorch`(i.e `torch.nn.Conv2d`)

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch, torch

I would like to know the difference between convolution layer in `Torch`(i.e `nn.SpatialConvolution`) and convolution layer in `Pytorch`(i.e `torch.nn.Conv2d`)

In `Torch`'s Docs, I found the output shape of `SpatialConvolution`

It says "If the input image is a 3D tensor `nInputPlane x height x width`, the output image size will be `nOutputPlane x oheight x owidth` where

```
owidth  = floor((width  + 2*padW - kW) / dW + 1)
oheight = floor((height + 2*padH - kH) / dH + 1)
```

"

which is different from `torch.nn.Conv2d`'s in Pytorch Docs.

[image: output shape of Conv2d in Pytorch]

Does it mean they are different operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are different as `torch` does not have `dilation` parameter (for dilation explanation see [here](http://www.erogol.com/dilated-convolution/), basically the kernel has "spaces" between each kernel element width and height wise and this is what slides over the image).

Except for `dilation` both equations are the same (set `dilation` to one in `pytorch`'s version and it's equal).

If you want to use `dilation` in `torch` there is a separate class for that called [`nn.SpatialDilatedConvolution`](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/convolution.md#nn.SpatialDilatedConvolution).

Comment: so `stride` is equal to `dilation` in default in `Torch`? Because I can't get same answer when `width` = `Win`, `padW` = `padding[0]`, `kW` = `kernel_size[0]`, `dW` = `dilation[0]` while `stride` = `1`(i.e default value in `Pytorch`)

Comment: @Chocoford No `dW = stride[0]` and `dilation = 1`. In Torch there is no dilation; i.e. dilation is always effectively 1 in Torch.